# Changing values in pre-formatted text using javascript

Tags: javascript, python

I want to have a script that will change specific values in a pre-formatted text. I tried doing this in javascript with ... undesirable success.

I want to have

```
<textbox1> 
...
<already formatted script><textbox1>
<rest of already formatted script>
...
```

or

```
<textbox2> 
...
<already formatted script><textbox1><more script>
<rest of already formatted script>
...
```

so I did something like this

```
<script>
function addusr() {

        document.getElementById("usrout").innerHTML = document.getElementById("usrin").value;
        }       
</script>
<body>

<input type="text" id="usrin" name="usrname" value="" />
<input type="button" value="Username" onClick="addusr()">

<div id="text">
<span id="usrout"></span>
</div>
```

and what I get is a continuous line of text with the span, but.. My text has specific breaks (A LOT OF them! so doing many span's for each line is undesirable and won't work for what I'm doing) what it will change is also a code, so it has to be specific. Ideally, I'd like it to be with an .html type file on my desktop, but if that's not possible then... alright, suggest an easy alternative please.

Comment: The way you have written this question is very confusing. I don't know how you're expected output is related to your input. I'm also not sure why this is related to Python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you either need to change the output to be a pre line breaks

```
#usrout { white-space: pre-wrap; }
```

OR change the new lines to break elements `<br/>`

Comment: I can do that in the css file?

Comment: Making sure I understood your solution. Thank you.